# Error org.json.JSONException: Value 1 at error of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to boolean

Tags: android, json

this is my script :

```js
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
 
 private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
 private Button btnLogin;
 private Button btnLinkToRegister;
 private EditText inputEmail;
 private EditText inputPassword;
 private ProgressDialog pDialog;
 private SessionManager session;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

  inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
  inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
  btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
  btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

  
  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
  pDialog.setCancelable(false);

  
  session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

  
  if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
   
   Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   finish();
  }

  
  btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(View view) {
    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

    
    if (email.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0) {
     
     checkLogin(email, password);
    } else {
     
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
       "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
       .show();
    }
   }

  });

  
  btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
      RegisterActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
   }
  });

 }


 private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
  
  String tag_string_req = "req_login";

  pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
  showDialog();

  StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
    AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

     @Override
     public void onResponse(String response) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
      hideDialog();

      try {
       JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
       boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

       
       if (!error) {
        
        session.setLogin(true);

        
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
          MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
       } else {
        
        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
          errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
      } catch (JSONException e) {
       
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

     }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      hideDialog();
     }
    }) {

   @Override
   protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
    
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("tag", "login");
    params.put("idm", email);
    params.put("pwd", password);

    return params;
   }

  };

  
  AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
 }

 private void showDialog() {
  if (!pDialog.isShowing())
   pDialog.show();
 }

 private void hideDialog() {
  if (pDialog.isShowing())
   pDialog.dismiss();
 }
}
```

and the logcat shows :

> org.json.JSONException: Value 1 at error of type java.lang.Integer
>   cannot be converted to boolean

i use this script to make a login page with my own database. this script is using email as username but in my database, i use numbers as username.

Comment: `This is my script` - grrrrrrr.

Comment: i mean i have a problem and this is the script. download it from www.androidhive.info :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
```

If "error" in your json object is not "true" or "false", you will get the exception:

> Value 1 at error of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to
>   boolean.

Instead use

```
int intError = jObj.getInt("error");
boolean error = (intError > 0) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
```

Your response "error" object not a boolean,so you can convert that as String or Integer based on your `exception` message.Try like below

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
boolean error = jObj.getString("error");
// or
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
boolean error = jObj.getInteger("error");
```